# Pentaho database lookup to fetch data

Tags: sql, pentaho

I have a database table, "FTTAGS" which has below 3 fields.

FTDATA

INST

KEY

FTDATA has value as shown below.
19,40,92,27456,1,9,6,7,121,6,7,5,01,24001,523247,19,005,12,6,7,222,2,98,1241222514,0,3933602,2745,8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,16,6,6,6,335,19,40,92,2745,1,9,6,7,2745,8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,16,6,6,6,335,98,5,01,204198,192,9,47,47,20,5,12,6,7,12,6,7

INST has value
"Frequecy -21 0x337811 gf.2241"

I need to search for "3933602" and fetch corresponding KEY .

I am not able to get any option in database lookup to do the same. Please help. I tried running a sql query using "Execute sql script". But it is not returning any values.

I tried below in execute sql script. But it did not return the output value.

select KEY from FTTAGS where INSTR(FTDATA,'?') > 0 AND INST like '?';

Comment: Try `LIKE` operator like `',' + FTDATA + ',' LIKE ',3933602,'` ;).

Comment: Share what you have tried.

Comment: I have huge records . Using "LIKE" is costly

Answer (score 0):

By using **Database join** step. You can achieve the goal. Let us see how to achieve these goal.

```
SQL: select * from FTTAGS where FTDATA = 3933602;
```

Take **Database join** step to canvas.

```
SQL: select * from FTTAGS where FTDATA = ?;
```

Follow below image for clear clarification.

[image]

If you want both results. You can follow below image.
  [image]

**Database join step:**

```
SQL: select * from FTTAGS
```

**Filter step:**

```
<field> => FTDATA                         
operateor => =                                    
<value> => 3933602
```

=> Red mark dummy step gives not satisfied result.
=> green tick mark dummy step gives satisfied result.

---

I think these information will useful to you.

Database join_1 step:

```
SQL: select * from FTTAGS where FTDATA = 3933602
```

Database join_2 step:

```
SQL: select * from FTTAGS where FTDATA <> 3933602
```

For clear clarification purpose you can see the below image

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: database join will allow only those for which KEY is present. It does not allow the rest of the data. In database lookup, we have this "Do not pass the row if the lookup fails" option

Comment: what you want? you want only those key data only right?

Comment: I want those which have been mapped as well as those which does not have "KEY"

Comment: Is there any way , wherein I can directly write a sql query?? ,,

Comment: I updated my answer check it once. You satisfied my answer can you give a tick mark please.

Comment: But it does not provide the unmapped ones. I checked.

Comment: How come "Execute sql script" does not provide output values??..  I can successfuly create tables,etc..

Comment: Have you tried checking the `Outer Join?` checkbox?

Comment: Venkatesh - The filter step condition is not correct. I am fetching "KEY", and it should check whether "KEY" value is null or not. But, "database join" step is not parsing those which does not have "KEY" mapped.